# Get shape of unknown tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to implement simple Q-Network for OpenAI gym. I've got placehoder for state. State is represented as integer. I want a one-hot vector. So, I do this:

```
input_state = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None))
state_oh = tf.one_hot(input_state, env.observation_space.n)
```

I am using `(None`) except `()` becouse I want to pass batch to train network.

I expected, that `state_oh` has shape like `(None, 16)`, but I got `<unknown>`. That is a problem for me, becouse I implement function to create fully-connected layer, which determine input tensor's shape using `tensor.shape`:

```
def dense(x, output_size, activation, name=None):  
with tf.name_scope(name, "dense", [x]):       

    w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_size, output_size]), name="w")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, output_size]), name="b")
    layer = tf.matmul(x, w) + b
    layer_act = activation(layer)

    return layer_act
```

This isn't work with `<unknown>` shape.

How can I pass batch of Integer to Tensorflow and get it's second dimension (length of one-hot vector)? I prefer don't pass input's size to `dense()` explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, that if I define my placeholder like this:

```
input_state = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None], name="input_state")
```

I made a very silly mistake. Correct shape is `[None]` instead `(None)`, becouse `(None)` is equivalent to `None`, which means "any shape".

With correct shape of placeholder, the shape of `state_oh` will be `(?, 16)` as an expected.